# Accessing arrays whitout quoting the key

Tags: php, syntax

I can access an array value either with `$array[key]` or `$array['key']`

Is there a reason to avoid using one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the latter variant `$array['key']`. The former will only work because PHP is tolerant and assumes the string value `key` if there is no constant named *key*:

> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, `$foo['bar']` is correct, while `$foo[bar]` is not. […] This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this […] has an undefined constant (`bar`) rather than a string (`'bar'` - notice the quotes).

See also [*Array do's and don'ts*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

Now in opposite to accessing arrays in plain PHP code, when using [variable parsing in double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) you actually need to write it without quotes or use the [curly brace syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> […] inside a double-quoted string, it's valid to not surround array indexes with quotes so `"$foo[bar]"` is valid. See the above examples for details on why as well as the section on variable parsing in strings.

So:

```
// syntax error
echo "$array['key']";

// valid
echo "$array[key]";
echo "{$array['key']}";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP will raise a warning for the quote-less version (`$array[key]`) if there's no constant named `key`defined, and silently convert it to `$array['key']`. Consider the trouble you'd have debugging your code if you had something:

```
$array['foo'] = 'baZ'
echo $array[foo];
echo $array['foo'];
echo "$array[foo]";
echo "{$array['foo']}";
echo "{$array[foo]}";

define('foo', 'baR');
echo $array[foo];
echo $array['foo'];
echo "$array[foo]";
echo "{$array['foo']}";
echo "{$array[foo]}";
```

Try them out and see, but make sure you've got warnings enabled (`error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `display_errors(1)`)

Answer (score 0):

`$array[key]` is not correct usage. In this case 'key' will be treated as a constant (i.e., via define()) instead of a string. In the case where there is no constant named key, PHP will assume you mean 'key' and "fix" it for you and throw a warning.