# would it make a difference if I omit single quotes in $_variable['variable']?

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing arrays whitout quoting the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891832/accessing-arrays-whitout-quoting-the-key)

I noticed there's a subtle difference... if I were to code this:

```
echo "Welcome, $_SESSION['username'], you are logged in.";
```

It will fail at parsing. However if I code like this:

```
echo "Welcome, $_SESSION[username], you are logged in.";
```

It works as expected which makes me wonder if single quotes are really necessary? I cannot find anything in PHP documentation showing that effect.

Comment: usually, you'd have to use `{$_SESSION['username']}` inside strings (the php docs are clear about this). apart from that, all variables output to an html page should be escaped using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Within the "complex curly" section it explains why it is bad.

Comment: rule of thumb, if your working with a variable break out of the string and concatenate

Comment: @myself... I mistakenly thought you were using the `${}` syntax, so my comment doesn't directly apply to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, a global constant that isn't defined [becomes a string](http://codepad.org/xhx1grYs).

[Don't rely on this](http://codepad.org/6UCVXz9k); **always** quote your array keys.

**However**, interpolated into a string, [it is fine](http://codepad.org/XCeLpqyf), as it is already a string.

[Konforce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259778/konforce) makes a good point in the comments about using braces in string interpolation.

If you omit them, [don't quote the key](http://codepad.org/FioV4DkN).

If you use them, [you must quote the key](http://codepad.org/J2hF0Geq), otherwise the constant will be [looked up](http://codepad.org/Y6GUSObe).

Comment: your answer is correct but it's worth pointing out that only because he isn't using curly braces. That is `echo "{$foo[bar]}"` is wrong but `echo "$foo[bar]"` is okay. Probably just my personal bias, but the latter format seems dirty to me.

Comment: @konforce Thanks, I made an update :)

Comment: like how you make it so concise with a few facts in a list... like that. :) THanks to konforce as well.

Answer (score 3):

This way is wrong but works`$_SESSION[username]` and take more time to parse the value of that associative index.

That effect PHP performance

> Always use quotes around a string
>   literal array index. For example,
>   $foo['bar'] is correct, while
>   $foo[bar] is not. This is wrong, but
>   it works. The reason is that this code
>   has an undefined constant (bar) rather
>   than a string ('bar' - notice the
>   quotes).PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

you should use quotes while accessing values.

Comment: I think you didn't notice that he's using variables inside a double quoted string.

Comment: @ThiefMaster:That does not matter here. He is asking why should use quotes to access array values even if that is working without the quotes

Comment: This will be helpful if **downvoter** leave a comment

Comment: That's not deprecated. The quote-less PHP3-style syntax within double quote context is correct. -- It is incorrect in PHP context and will indeed lead to notice/performance issues.

Comment: @Shakti: The cited part is correct, as is your reasoning. But it does still not apply to specifically what OP asked. In double quotes there is a special handling for simple array resolving. And the unquoted array keys will not be probed or interpreted or auto-defined as constants (much unlike they would in real PHP array expressions). And the fun fact is, it's actually faster to use the bare-key syntax within double quoted strings.

Comment: @mario, To be fair to @Singh, I think the question asker was trying to ask "I noticed that using single quotes within a quoted string is invalid, so do I really need to use them when accessing an array outside of a string?".

Comment: @konforce: True, the question title suggests something different than the text body. And bare array keys are a syntax error in my book too. It's just important to point out that there's indeed a specific syntax variation in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) document

in section `Array do's and don'ts`

```
<?php
// Show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$arr = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'veggie' => 'carrot');

// Correct
print $arr['fruit'];  // apple
print $arr['veggie']; // carrot

// Incorrect.  This works but also throws a PHP error of level E_NOTICE because
// of an undefined constant named fruit
// 
// Notice: Use of undefined constant fruit - assumed 'fruit' in...
print $arr[fruit];    // apple

// This defines a constant to demonstrate what's going on.  The value 'veggie'
// is assigned to a constant named fruit.
define('fruit', 'veggie');

// Notice the difference now
print $arr['fruit'];  // apple
print $arr[fruit];    // carrot

// The following is okay, as it's inside a string. Constants are not looked for
// within strings, so no E_NOTICE occurs here
print "Hello $arr[fruit]";      // Hello apple

// With one exception: braces surrounding arrays within strings allows constants
// to be interpreted
print "Hello {$arr[fruit]}";    // Hello carrot
print "Hello {$arr['fruit']}";  // Hello apple

// This will not work, and will result in a parse error, such as:
// Parse error: parse error, expecting T_STRING' or T_VARIABLE' or T_NUM_STRING'
// This of course applies to using superglobals in strings as well
print "Hello $arr['fruit']";
print "Hello $_GET['foo']";

// Concatenation is another option
print "Hello " . $arr['fruit']; // Hello apple
?>
```

Comment: That's a huge document. You could improve this answer by quoting the specific section that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a string you **have** to omit the single quotes or wrap the whole variable in `{}` (`"...{$array['key']}..."` or `...$array[key]...`). However, wrapping it is highly recommended to prevent issues when having something like `"...$foobar..."` where you actually wanted `"...{$foo}bar..."` (i.e. the var `$foo` followed by `bar`).

But you might not want to use in-string vars at all but properly end the string: `'...' . $var . '...'`

Comment: @Daric: Maybe you should understand the answer before downvoting...

Answer (score 0):

It's called bare strings as mentioned, strangly enough, in the [array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). If no constant is found matching the bare string - It's, for historical reasons, assumbed to be a string literal. This syntax is however ridden with a lot of syntactic problems that I won't go into, also readability is a problem here. The reader questions himself - Is this a constant or a string?

Modern PHP versions emit a warning for this syntax, as to help fix this problem by using singly quoted strings ('username').

Answer (score 0):

yes.
If you pass an argument for an array without any quotes, php will first try to interpret the argument as a constant and if it isn't defined, it will act as expected.Even though it can give the same result, it is significantly slower that the quoted argument.
Here's an example of when this might not work :

```
define("a_constant","a value");
$a = array("a_constant"=>"the right value");
echo $a[a_constant];
```

The `a_constant` variable has the value "a value", so `$a[a_constant]` gets translated to `$a["a value"]`, a key which does not exist in the array `$a`.