# URL lost during POST

Tags: php

What's wierd is that on one page I can echo a variable built by:

```
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
```

Then post it to another page (I know the post works because I send other values):

```
<?php echo'<input type="hidden" name="Refferer" value="'.$currentUrl.'"/>'?>
```

But when I try to use it on my other page it is now empty:

```
$return = $_Post[Refferer];
header("Location: $return");
```

Anyone know what's happening to it?

Comment: How does the generated html code looks like before you post form?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$return = $_POST['Refferer'];
header("Location: $return");
```

Comment: Yep, `$_Post[Refferer];` looks for a constant `Refferer` and try to use its content as the variable name. Since you didn't declare such a constant, the actual variable you are requesting is `$_Post[null];`, which isn't set either.

Comment: Actually, PHP will accept single word strings as array indices without quoting. So the problem is not the quoting. I think it's the case-sensitive $_POST. The single-quoting I added is just good form.

Comment: OK, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891832/accessing-arrays-whitout-quoting-the-key

Answer (score 3):

$_POST is case sensitive.

Try to use $_POST instead of $_Post.

Comment: but other vars (vars in php are not case sensitive, I mean) aren’t AFAIK?

Comment: The variable name is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="Refferer" value="'.urlencode($currentUrl).'"/>' ?>
```