# HTML code within PHP function

Tags: php, html

I have html code within a php function and it is displaying everything I need. I however find it very difficult to understand the use of `.` and `'` when splitting up the code. I wish to change the layout to put the values within a table but struggle to get the correct syntax. Currently it looks like this;

```
$sub = $get_row['price']*$value; // Creates Subtotal of product
echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound; '.number_format($sub, 2).'
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> 
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&add='.$id.'">[+]</a> 
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br/>';
```

Is there a good tutorial/example about how to easily style this? Can anyone guide me in how this should be styled?

I am looking to put it in the following;

```
<table>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Subtotal</th>
.....
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  If you're looking for style guides, a routine internet search should find many.

Comment: ...and if you don't understand how string concatenation in php works, then you can look at the manual, the English description of strings and their operators is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is something like this

```
while($row - mysqli_fetch_array($here is your query)){
     $id = $row["id"];
     $name = $row["name"];

    $html .='
           <a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&remove='.$id.'">[-]</a>
           <a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&add='.$id.'">[+]</a> 
           <a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br/>';

 }
 ?>
<html>
    <?php echo $html;?>
```

In this it loops through your query and for each ID it finds it creates your links and appends it to the $html variable. Then when you echo they will display in order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using quoteless keys (see [Accessing arrays whitout quoting the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891832/accessing-arrays-whitout-quoting-the-key)), I find that putting your variables inside of double quotes when possible makes the entire string more readable and reduces the amount of concatenation you need to do.

```
echo "$get_row[name] x  $value  @ &pound;".number_format($get_row['price'], 2)." = &pound; ".number_format($sub, 2);
```

If you want that even more readable, store the `number_format` calculations in variables first.

Also, for big strings of html, I like to close out php and use tags to echo the variables, because it's more readable to me (I prefer short echo tags (`<?=` `?>`), but it's officially not encouraged so I can't officially recommend it here ;) ).

```
?>
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&remove=<?php echo $id?>">[-]</a> 
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&add=<?php echo $id?>">[+]</a> 
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=cart.php&delete=<?php echo $id?>">[Delete]</a><br/>
<?
```