# Fill jQuery DataTables with drop down and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I'm working with DataTables and this is my scenario:

1)I've got a drop down menu with some user's name and their proper ID;
2)I've got an empty DataTable;
3)I would like to detect user's ID selecting one row from drop drown menu, pass it to server_processing.php(DB query) using `data:` property of DataTables and display DB query's result back in Data Table.

Code for drop down:

```
<select id="selezione_user" name="selezione_user" class="select2 form-control">
<option value="">Seleziona</option>
<?php $query=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,nome FROM user ORDER BY nome",$conn);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          echo "<option value='$row[user_id]'>$row[nome]</option>";
    }?>
</select>
```

Code for DataTable (HTML):

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="prova">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>User</th>
<th>Comune</th>
<th>Mail</th>
<th>Stato</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Code for DataTable (JS)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#prova').dataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
       "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
       "data": {
          "user_id": null //set to show empty DataTable
       }
   },
});

$('#selezione_user').change(function() {
     aoData.push({
     "user_id": this.value            
})
}); 
});
```

But the code above doesn't work and this problem is driving me crazy, I hope someone will help me.
Thanks to all.
Giacomo.

**EDIT**

I solved my problem using removing `data:` and changing DataTables(JQuery) function in this way:

```
    $('#selezione_centri').change(function() {
     var valore = this.value;
     var string = ('scripts/server_processing.php?id_professionista='+valore);
     table.ajax.url(string).load();
     table.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the row

```
echo "<option value='$row[user_id]'>$row[nome]</option>";
```

Try changing it to

```
echo "<option value='".$row["user_id"]."'>".$row["nome"]."</option>";
```

This is somewhat explained here: [Accessing arrays whitout quoting the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891832/accessing-arrays-whitout-quoting-the-key) , the php array keys need to be quoted. This is merely a longshot here!

For more precise debugging (if this is not enough), you should provide the php code.

Comment: You're right. I correct PHP issue and I got the same error. I could post server_processing.php but it's a long script and It works fine (if I pass a user_id statically.I think error is linked with aoData.push.

Comment: What if you try the line `oTable.fnDraw();` right after the aoData.push

Comment: I solved my problem. I've edited my post introducing a working way. Thanks to all.